# Absence of base domain certificate for SEO

Tags: ssl, https, seo, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have the following situation:

Customer bought certificate for **www.example.com** instead of
***.example.com** , that's why when you go to https://example.com/ you can see: "Your connection is not private" ssl warning.

The questions are :

1)  Does it have impact on SEO ?

2) Is it some workaround for that without asking for buying new certificate ?

Comment: If you are using Apache, you can try the _mod_rewrite_ that will forward all traffic from http[s]://example.com to https://www.example.com (other web servers will have similar options). But that won't help for the initial connection from https://example.com: it will still issue a warning since the SSL layer will be resolved before the redirection is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if the site is available via two URLs (www. and non-www.) then this in itself is an SEO problem. Google sees each URL iteration as a separate page so this may be causing a serious duplicate content issue.

You can read more about [this and other causes of duplicate content here](https://yoast.com/duplicate-content/#www).

To answer your direct question - yes, the SSL warning will have an impact on SEO. As a rule of thumb with SEO, just ask yourself how something will impact a user's experience. If this answer is 'bad' then this is probably going to have a negative SEO effect as well.

To fix it, you need some redirects in place.

For an Apache server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /srv/www/example.com/keys/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/example.com/keys/www.example.com.key;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But warning will still exists, because SSL layer goes before redirect ?

Comment: Serve site over www. only and redirect all traffic to www. and this will solve it (without having to buy new cert)